# Rails: calling yield in a partial template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I see this sometimes in a partial erb template:

```
<%= yield :someval %>
```

Other times there is no yield at all.

What's the advantage of calling yield in a partial?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have used it in the past if I have a partial that could be called from different pages that might need some contextual content from the page.

A use case that I had was for a menu.  I had my stock menu items, but then I had a `yield(:menu)`, so that what the user loaded the administration page, I could add menu items from the page instead of writing a condition statement in the partial itself.

This is some pseudo code:

#### _menu.haml

```
%ul
  %li Home
  %li Users
  %li Roles
  = yield(:menu)
```

#### users.haml

```
- content_for :menu do
  %li Add User
  %li Change permissions
```

#### roles.haml

```
- content_for :menu do
  %li Add Role
```

As opposed to:

```
%ul
  %li Home
  %li Users
  %li Roles
  - if current_controller == 'users'
    %li Add User
    %li Change permissions
  - if current_controller == 'roles'
    %li Add Role
```

While both are functional (if it was real code), I prefer the first method.  The second can spiral out of control and get pretty ugly pretty fast.  It is a matter of preference though.

Comment: In this case, is `_menu.haml` a layout or a partial?  And if it's the latter, where is the render call for this partial being made?   What happens if you want to render the same partial twice in a view but have a different `content_for` for each.  How do you specify that you want `content_for :menu { :foo }` for one, and that you want `content_for :menu { :bar } for the other?

Comment: This particular case was just psuedocode, so it would be a partial that would need to eventually get rendered in a layout. if you wanted to render the same partial in multiple places with different yield statements. You could pass the :menu as a variable to the partial so you could differentiate. So a `render partial: :menu, locals: {menu: :custom_name_1}` with a `yield(menu)` and then `content_for :custom_name_1, { :bar }`